# Git diff gone mad?

Tags: git, msysgit, tortoisegit, git-diff

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my local Git repo.

1. I edit a file.
2. Git reports **everything** has changed in the file (I only changed **one** line)
3. At first I think "must be a newline problem", but it's not. I do a diff in TortoiseGit, everything looks fine. I do a diff with Netbeans (git plugin), everything seems fine.
4. I do a reset, backup the file, modify it, git again reports everything has changed.
5. I do a binary compare in Total Commander, the files have *no differences* except for the single line I changed.
6. I do a hard reset again. Git tells me it was done successfully. Git status *still* says my file has changed. I diff the thing and there are no differences - bug git says there are.

I've tried using both git bash and gui, with same results (I'm on Windows). Any clues, what's going on here?

Comment: It happens only with this repository or all repositories? Though you think it's not a newline problem, check parameter `core.autocrlf` (`git config --get core.autocrlf`) anyway, it should be `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I've committed the file in question, I've restarted the workstation and now everything seems in order (I've tried editing some other files in the same repo and diff was fine).

Have no idea what happened. I'm writing this one down as "Windows"...

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses different line feed characters, when you edit the file in the Windows environment you use those settings, then when Git looks at it it doesn't recognize the line feed. You can try using vi to set the fileformat to unix which will convert all linefeed characters to the unix style: set ff=unix 
Hope that helps